# I need help on my program's while loop

Tags: java, while-loop

The instructions for the program:

You have just purchased a stereo system that cost $1,000 on the following credit plan: no down payment, an interest rate of 18% per year (and hence 1.5% per month), and monthly payments of $50. The monthly payment of $50 is used to pay the interest, and whatever is left is used to pay part of the remaining debt. Hence, the first month you pay 1.5% on $1,000 in interest. That is $15 dollars in interest. So, the remaining $35 is deducted from your debt, which leaves you with a debt of $965.00. The next month, you pay interest of 1.5% on that $965.00, which is $14.48. Hence you can deduct $35.52 (which is 50 - 14.48) from the amount you owe (965.00 - 14.48). Write a program that tells you how many months it will take you to pay off the loan, as well as the total amount of interest paid over the life of the loan. Use a loop to calculate the amount of interest and the size of the debt after each month. Use a variable to count the number of loop iterations and hence, the number of months until the debt is zero. The last payment may be less than 50 if the debt is small, but do not forget the interest.

Here is my code so far:

```
    public class ProgrammingProject5
    {
         public static void main(String[] args)
         {
              double startingDebt = 1000;
              double interestPerMonth = 0.015;
              double moneyDuePerMonth = 50;
              double debt = startingDebt;
              int m = 0;

              while (debt > 0)
              {
                    double monthlyInterest = (startingDebt*interestPerMonth);
                    double monthlyOwed = moneyDuePerMonth - monthlyInterest;

                    debt = startingDebt - monthlyOwed;

                    m++;
              }

              System.out.println("The amount of months until debt is 0:  " + m);
     }
 }
```

I know I am doing it wrong and that my month output is wrong. If anyone could help me that would be greatly appreciated. (I am really stuck).

Comment: So the code itself runs? This really seems like more of a math question than a java question.

Comment: "I know I am doing it wrong and that my month output is wrong" What does the code do, and what do you expect it to do instead?

Comment: You're calculating the monthly interest using the starting balance each time, I believe it should be calculated by the current balance instead.

Comment: The indentation gets weird near the end. javac won't care, but some humans will.

Comment: You don't need a `startingDebt` variable. Just initialize `debt` as `1000` and use `debt` in placd of `startingDebt` in your loop. The reason you're getting the wrong output is because you're using `startingDebt` (which you never change) in place of `debt` (which should change).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The amount of interest owed each month is calculated on the current balance, not the beginning balance. This really isn't the right place for this question though. Try this.

```
public class ProgrammingProject5 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double startingDebt = 1000;
        double interestPerMonth = 0.015;
        double moneyDuePerMonth = 50;
        double debt = startingDebt;
        int m = 0;

        while (debt > 0) {
            double monthlyInterest = (debt*interestPerMonth);
            double monthlyOwed = moneyDuePerMonth - monthlyInterest;

            debt = debt - monthlyOwed;

            m++;
        }

        System.out.println("The amount of months until debt is 0:  " + m);
    }
}
```